# get and view only a specific pdf page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf

I have a pdf file and on a button click want to display only a specific page
So I set the current page number on client side - for example `var x = 5`
on server side I need something like this:

```
$pages = explode('page_break', 'test.pdf');
$page = $pages[$x];
$html = convert_pdf_to_html($page);
echo $html;
```

another idea - preview the specific page without rendering as html - if possible

any help, pls

Comment: I don't think there's anything built-in, so you'd have to look for libraries with the option.

Comment: Use a PDF reader and get the page data. https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tc-lib-pdf-page/source-class-Com.Tecnick.Pdf.Page.Page/#293-306

Answer (score 0):

Display where? In the browser?

As far as I'm aware there aren't any libraries in PHP to create HTML from PDF. You'll need to use an external service.

Having said that, your use case is quite odd. You can display PDF somewhat natively in the browser nowadays:

In your markup:

```html
<a href="/your/app/files.pdf" target="_blank">See Your PDF</a>
```

Then, in your PHP script/controller that handles that route:

```php
$pdfContents = file_get_contents('/your/pdf/file.pdf');

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
echo $pdfContents;
```

This **does not handle specific pages** though. For that you will need a converter.

Comment: display in browser, of course, not on tv. And the question is about displaying a specific pdf page